# How can I change the colors of the edges in a graph created by tkz-graph in LaTeX

Tags: tkz-graph

I'm trying to change the colors of two of the edges in the basic graph created by the tkz-graph LaTeX code below to red and the other two to blue and I can't seem to find a way to do it... Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, verbatim, inputenc, graphicx, bbold, 
float, calc, bm, dsfont, tikz, pgf, mathtools}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\GraphInit[vstyle = Normal]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\graphicspath{ {C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Tropical\main document} }


\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    LabelStyle/.append style = { rectangle, draw, minimum width = 2em, fill = white, text = black},
    VertexStyle/.append style = { inner sep=5pt,
        font = \Large\bfseries},
    EdgeStyle/.append style = {->} 
}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetGraphUnit{5}
    \Vertex{1}
    \EA(1){2}
    \SO(1){3}
    \EA(3){4}
    \Edge[color=blue](1)(2)
    \Edge[color=blue](3)(1)
    \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {->, bend left}}
    \Edge[color=red](3)(4)
    \Edge[color=red](4)(3)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It would also be fine if I could make them dashed and not dashed edge lines instead of different colors, but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: In a minimal document the colours appear fine.  Please complete your code to such a document demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, I have completed the code as asked, I still get the graph in black and white.

Comment: Seems to be because of `\GraphInit[vstyle = Normal]`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, getting rid of that has it working now, thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your `color` settings doesn't work appear to be the `\GraphInit[vstyle = Normal]`, removing that and your code works.

You can alternatively add `red` and `blue` to your two `\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {...}}` declarations. That is, if you have `\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style={red}}`, the following `\Edge`s will be red. Note that `append style` doesn't overwrite the existing definition of the style, if you do want to replace the existing style use `\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={...}}`.

Finally, a little comment on your preamble. You load several packages several times, albeit implicitly, so it can be cleaned up a bit:

- `tkz-graph` loads TikZ, which loads `pgf`, so the latter two are not needed. TikZ actually also loads `graphicx`.
- The `amsart` class loads `amsmath` and `amsthm`, and it loads `amsfonts`, which in turn loads `amssymb`. (`mathtools` also loads `amsmath`, but it extends it as well, so that can be kept.)

Normally when using the `inputenc` package, you would specify the encoding of your `.tex` file in the optional argument, e.g. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{
  verbatim,
  inputenc,
  float,
  calc,
  bm,
  mathtools,
  bbold,
  dsfonts
}

\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\GraphInit[vstyle = Normal]
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\graphicspath{ {C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\Tropical\main document} }

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    LabelStyle/.append style = { rectangle, draw, minimum width = 2em, fill = white, text = black},
    VertexStyle/.append style = { inner sep=5pt,
        font = \Large\bfseries},
    EdgeStyle/.append style = {->,blue} % added blue
}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \SetGraphUnit{5}
    \Vertex{1}
    \EA(1){2}
    \SO(1){3}
    \EA(3){4}
    \Edge[color=blue](1)(2)
    \Edge[color=blue](3)(1)
    \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.append style = {bend left,red}} % added red
    \Edge[color=red](3)(4)
    \Edge[color=red](4)(3)
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```